# Negative goes positive when tying to convert DMS to Lat/lon

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've been sitting with an error for quite some time. I'm working with coordinates, trying to convert coordinates from Decimal Degrees to DMS and back again, with a checkbox.

This is current code (JS Fiddle):
https://jsfiddle.net/Mtihc/m2n8tejs/61/
HTML:

```
<label>Lat</label><input id="latitude" type="text" value="-8.3692° S"/>
<label>Long</label><input id="longtitude" type="text" value="115.1383° E"/>
<input id="dmstoggler" type="checkbox"/>
<br/>
<label id="dmstoggler_state">Decimal degrees</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("#dmstoggler").on('change', function (eventInfo) {
  let longInput = document.getElementById("longtitude")
  let latInput = document.getElementById("latitude")
  if (eventInfo.target.checked) {
    // convert to DMS
    let long = parseFloat(longInput.value.replace(/° \w/, ""))
    let lat = parseFloat(latInput.value.replace(/° \w/, ""))
    let dms = convertDMS(lat, long)
    longInput.value = dms.long;
    latInput.value = dms.lat;
  } else {
    // convert back to long/lat
    let longdms = longInput.value.replace(/[^\d\s]/g, "").split(' ').map(n => parseFloat(n))
    let latdms = latInput.value.replace(/[^\d\s]/g, "").split(' ').map(n => parseFloat(n))
    let latlong = convertLatLong(latdms, longdms)
    longInput.value = latlong.long
    latInput.value = latlong.lat
  }
  $("#dmstoggler_state").html(eventInfo.target.checked ? "DMS" : "Decimal degrees")
})

function toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(coordinate) {
    var absolute = Math.abs(coordinate);
    var degrees = Math.floor(absolute);
    var minutesNotTruncated = (absolute - degrees) * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(minutesNotTruncated);
    var seconds = Math.floor((minutesNotTruncated - minutes) * 60);
        if (coordinate < 0) degrees *= -1;
    return degrees + "° " + minutes + "' " + seconds;
}

function convertDMS(lat, lng) {
    var latitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat);
    var latitudeCardinal = lat > 0 ? "'' N" : "'' S";

    var longitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng);
    var longitudeCardinal = lng > 0 ? "'' E" : "'' W";

    return {
      lat: latitude + latitudeCardinal,
      long: longitude + longitudeCardinal
    }
}


function convertLatLong(lat, long) {
  let dmslat = lat[0] + (lat[1]/60) + (lat[2]/3600)
  let dmslong = long[0] + (long[1]/60) + (long[2]/3600)
  dmslat = parseFloat(dmslat.toFixed(4))
  dmslong = parseFloat(dmslong.toFixed(4))
  if (lat[0] < 0) dmslat *= -1;
  if (long[0] < 0) dmslong *= -1;
  return {
    lat: dmslat + "° " + (lat[0] > 0 ? "N" : "S"),
    long: dmslong + "° " + (long[0] > 0 ? "E" : "W"),
  }

}
```

As you can see it starts at: **-8.3692° S**

After converting from Lat / Lon to DMS (works great), converting back to Lat / lon is an issue. When converting back to Lat / Lon it returns the value.

When converting back to Lat / lon it returns: **8.3692° N**

We suspect a math issue, but can't locate the specific issue. As you can se it goes from **Negative South** to **Positive North**, how can this be?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not dealing with negative values properly because you're stripping the `-` signs out with `let latdms = latInput.value.replace(/[^\d\s]/g, "").split(' ').map(n => parseFloat(n))` the character class should include `-` i.e. `/[^\d\s-]/g`. Beyond that you have other issues...

Comment: Hi @Nick - Thank you for your answer. What other issues can you identify?

Comment: I didn't look into it in a lot more detail, but I think when `lat[0]` is negative, you also need to consider `lat[1]` and `lat[2]` as being negative when you're doing the conversion back.

Comment: I can't help with the Javascript but -8.3692ºS - what do you mean by this? If you are using N and S then eight degrees south is 8ºS not -8ºS. -8ºS actually means 8ºN which is what you are getting with your calculation.